# Cakephp - If Request is JSON?

Tags: json, cakephp

I have read the `RequestHandler` part in [cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/request-handling.html). There are `isXml()`, `isRss()`, etc. But there's no `isJson()`.

Any other way to check whether a request is JSON?

So when the url is `mysite.com/products/view/1.json` it will give JSON data, but without `.json` it will give the HTML View.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I dont think cakePHP has some function like isJson() for json data, you could create your custom though, like:

```
//may be in your app controller
function isJson($data) {
  return (json_decode($data) != NULL) ? true : false; 
}
//and you can use it in your controller
if( $this->isJson($your_request_data) ) {
 ... 
}
```

Added:
if you want to check .json extension and process accordingly, then you could do in your controller:

```
$this->request->params['ext']; //which would give you 'json' if you have .json extension
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, maybe my question is a bit confusing. I want the site to return JSON data when it have `.json` at the end of the URL, otherwise return normal HTML View

Comment: I used `$this->request->params['_ext']` for `CakePHP 3.8`.

Answer (score 8):

CakePHP is handling this correctly, because JSON is a response type and not a type of request. The terms request and response might be causing some confusing. The request object represents the header information of the HTTP request sent to the server. A browser usually sends POST or GET requests to a server, and those requests can *not* be formatted as JSON. So it's not possible for a request to be of type JSON.

With that said, the server can give a response of JSON and a browser can put in the request header that it supports a JSON response. So rather than check what the request was. Check what accepted responses are supported by the browser.

So instead of writing `$this->request->isJson()` you should write `$this->request->accepts('application/json')`.

This information is ambiguously shown in the [document here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#CakeRequest::accepts), but there is no reference `see also` links in the `is(..)` documentation. So many people look there first. Don't see JSON and assume something is missing.

If you want to use a request detector to check if the browser supports a JSON response, then you can easily add a one liner in your beforeFilter.

```
$this->request->addDetector('json',array('callback'=>function($req){return $req->accepts('application/json');}));
```

There is a risk associated with this approach, because a browser can send multiple response types as a possible response from the server. Including a wildcard for all types. So this limits you to only requests that indicate a JSON response is supported. Since JSON is a text format a type of `text/plain` is a valid response type for a browser expecting JSON.

We could modify our rule to include `text/plain` for JSON responses like this.

```
$this->request->addDetector('json',array('callback'=>function($req){
    return $req->accepts('application/json') || $req->accepts('text/plain');
}));
```

That would include text/plain requests as a JSON response type, but now we have a problem. Just because the browser supports a text/plain response doesn't mean it's expecting a JSON response.

This is why it's better to incorporate a naming convention into your URL to indicate a JSON response. You can use a `.json` file extension or a `/json/controller/action` prefix.

I prefer to use a named prefix for URLs. That allows you to create `json_action` methods in your controller. You can then create a detector for the prefix like this.

```
$this->request->addDetector('json',array('callback'=>function($req){return isset($req->params['prefix']) && $req->params['prefix'] == 'json';}));
```

Now that detector will always work correctly, but I argue it's an incorrect usage of detecting a JSON request. Since there is no such thing as a JSON request. Only JSON responses.

Answer (score 4):

You can make your own detectors. See: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#inspecting-the-request

For example in your AppController.php

```
public function beforeFilter() {
  $this->request->addDetector(
    'json',
    [
      'callback' => [$this, 'isJson']
    ]
  );
  parent::beforeFilter();
}

public function isJson() {
  return $this->response->type() === 'application/json';
}
```

Now you can use it:

```
$this->request->is('json'); // or
$this->request->isJson();
```

Comment: Hi Thanks, I will try to use this when I need this function again.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked through and followed the very detailed instructions in the book?:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html

Comment: I don't think I need custom view for this since I just need the pure query result from database. But if this is the only way, I guess I will follow it. So in my `controller`, I don't need any `if` statement saying like `if(json) render this`?

Comment: You don't need to use a custom view if you want to respond with json. They're just telling you that you *can* use a custom view. By using Router::parseExtensions('json') and loading the RequestHandler in your controller, you can simply write `$this->set('product', $product); $this->set('_serialize', 'product');` and it will automagically respond with json if your request has a `Accept: application/json` header or render the view file if your request has `Accept: text/html`. You shouldn't check is('type') all the time because content type negotiation can be handled for you!

Answer (score 1):

```
class TestController extends Controller {

    public $autoRender = false;

    public function beforeFilter() {
        $this->request->addDetector('json', array('env' => 'CONTENT_TYPE', 'pattern' => '/application\/json/i'));
        parent::beforeFilter();
    }

    public function index() {
        App::uses('HttpSocket', 'Network/Http');

        $url = 'http://localhost/myapp/test/json';
        $json = json_encode(
            array('foo' => 'bar'),
            JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_AMP
        );
        $options = array('header' => array('Content-Type' => 'application/json'));

        $request = new HttpSocket();
        $body = $request->post($url, $json, $options)->body;

        $this->response->body($body);
    }

    public function json() {

        if ($this->request->isJson()) {
            $data = $this->request->input('json_decode');
            $value = property_exists($data, 'foo') ? $data->foo : '';  
        }

        $body = (isset($value) && $value === 'bar') ? 'ok' : 'fail';
        $this->response->body($body);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the addition. This will be useful for other

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot Mr @Schlaefer. I read your comment and try, Wow it's working now.

```
//AppController.php

function beforeFilter() {
        $this->request->addDetector(
                'json', [
            'callback' => [$this, 'isJson']
                ]
        );
        parent::beforeFilter();
       ...
    }


public function isJson() {
        return $this->response->type() === 'application/json';
    }
//TasksController.php

public $components = array('Paginator', 'Flash', Session','RequestHandler');
```

//Get tasks function return all tasks in json format

```
public function getTasks() {
        $limit = 20;
        $conditions = array();
        if (!empty($this->request->query['status'])) {
            $conditions = ['Task.status' => $this->request->query['status']];
        }
        if (!empty($this->request->query['limit'])) {
            $limit = $this->request->query['limit'];
        }
        $this->Paginator->settings = array('limit' => $limit, 'conditions' => $conditions);

        $tasks = $this->paginate();

        if ($this->request->isJson()) {

            $this->set(
array(
                'tasks' => $tasks,
                '_serialize' => array('tasks')
            ));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody is reading this in the days of CakePHP 4, the correct and easy way to do this is by using `$this->request->is('json')`.